# String replacing in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I want to replace a particular string in `#TextArea1`. This happens when a button is clicked.

Trying it out with the below code, but unable to get it work:

```
$('#TextArea1').text().replace("wef","--");
```

What is the correct syntax to replace a word in a `div`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace()` creates a new string and returns it, so it's getting returned into thin air. You need to grab the new string and send it back into the textbox. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhDpr/) shows how.

```
<textarea id="t">
    hello
</textarea>
```

```
var text = $('#t').text();
text = text.replace('h', 'b');
$('#t').text(text);
```

Comment: Thanks Matt..That was the most simplest way, it suited well to my, little complicated code.

Comment: Def take a look at the other answers though, they bring up some really good points.

Comment: this suited my code extremely well, though others have good points too.  Your code needed a line in, and no change in code, which is why your answer was accepted.  I voted up for every answer in appreciation.

Answer (score 14):

Pass a function to the [`text()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method  that returns the value you want set:

```
$('#TextArea1').text(function( i, txt ) { 
    return txt.replace("wef","--"); 
});
```

---

The function parameters are as follows:

- `i` is the index of the current element in the iteration
- `txt` is the current text content of the current element

The value returned from the function will be set as the new value for the current element.

Answer (score 6):

You are close, try this:

```
$('#TextArea1').text($('#TextArea1').text().replace(/wef/g,"--"));
```

---

Or an optimized one

```
var $textarea = $('#TextArea1');
$textarea.text($textarea.text().replace(/wef/g,"--"));
```

---

If it's a `textarea` element, you would do:

```
var $textarea = $('#TextArea1');
$textarea.val($textarea.val().replace(/wef/g,"--"));
```

Comment: +1 for replacing all instances, whereas other answers only replace the first instance. Not sure what OP's goal is, but I assume this would be part of it.

Answer (score 4):

You have set the text also:

```
var text = $('#TextArea1').text().replace("wef","--");
$('#TextArea1').text(text);
```

or, using a function:

```
$('#TextArea1').text(function(index, text) {
  return text.replace("wef","--");
});
```

Note: if this is a `<textarea>`, use `val()` instead of `text()`.

```
var text = $('#TextArea1').val().replace("wef","--");
$('#TextArea1').val(text);
```